# java sort string array according to kurdish characters

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Is there any short way to sort a string array by Kurdish characters? I've looked at some source on internet but I couldn't find any solution. There is a way to sort. Writing a code alike a novel but it is a very long work.

> kurdish characters: a,b,c,ç,d,e,ê,f,g,h,i,î,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,ş,t,û,u,v,w,x,y,z

Comment: implement your own comparision https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: @Mazlum If you like my answer, please consider marking it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: I tried but it said java.locale cannot be applied to char. After this error I hadnt work on it too much. But I will look at again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem: content of my file was like this:

> *Nîzamettîn Ariç - Kardeş Türküler - Rojek Tê
>   Bê xem bê şer welat azad rojek tê
>   Rojek ronahî rojek bişahî rojek tê
>   
> Roj Roja me ye....
>   *Koma Çiya - Tolhildan ^ Daketine Meydanê
>   Daketine meydanê gerilayên dînemêr
>   Ji bona tolhildanê wek baz û piling û şêr
> ...

My solution: thîs letters is proper for toLowerCase function:

> ABCÇDEÊFGĞHİÎJKLMNOÖPQRSŞTÛUÜVWXYZ

just **I** was problem. because lowerCase(I) for turkish is **ı**; but for kurdish it is **i**.

code:

```
in onCreate():
...
alfabetBike();
...
public static void alfabetBike() {
    for (int i = 0; i < tips.length(); i++) {
        String[] derbasi_arr = sernavs[i];
        String[] derbasi_got = gotins[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < hejmar[i] - 1; j++) {
            int indeks = j;
            String yaMezin = derbasi_arr[j];
            for (int k = j + 1; k < hejmar[i]; k++) {
                if (compareTwoString(yaMezin.substring(1), derbasi_arr[k].substring(1)) > 1) {
                    yaMezin = derbasi_arr[k];
                    indeks = k;
                }
            }
            if (indeks != j) {
                derbasi_arr[indeks] = derbasi_arr[j];
                String derbasi = derbasi_got[indeks];
                derbasi_got[indeks] = derbasi_got[j];
                derbasi_arr[j] = yaMezin;
                derbasi_got[j] = derbasi;
            }
        }
        gotins[i] = derbasi_got;
        sernavs[i] = derbasi_arr;
    }
}

private static void printFile(){
    alfabetBike();
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/alfabetfolder");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File(dir, "alfabet_title.txt");
    File file2 = new File(dir, "alfabet.txt");

    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file,false);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
        FileOutputStream f2 = new FileOutputStream(file2,false);
        PrintWriter pw2 = new PrintWriter(f2);

        for (int i = 0; i < tips.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < hejmar[i]; j++) {
                Log.d("ssdddddd", "add" + hejmar[i] + "-" + j + "  " + sernavs[i][j].trim());
                pw.println(sernavs[i][j]);
                pw.flush();
                pw2.println(sernavs[i][j]  + "\n" + gotins[i][j].trim());
                pw2.flush();
            }
        }
        pw.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("erroooor", "******* File not found. Did you" +
                " add a WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to the   manifest?");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static int compareTwoString(String yek, String du) {
    String d1 = yek, d2 = du;
    d1 = strLower(d1, d1.charAt(0));
    d2 = strLower(d2, d2.charAt(0));
    int length, yaDirej;

    if (yek.length() > du.length()) {
        yaDirej = 1;
        length = yek.length();
    } else if (yek.length() < du.length()) {
        yaDirej = 2;
        length = du.length();
    } else {
        yaDirej = 0;
        length = yek.length();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int id1 = -1, id2 = -1;
        if (i == d1.length() || i == du.length()) {
            return yaDirej;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < tips.length(); j++) {
            if (d1.charAt(i) == tips.charAt(j)) id1 = j;
            if (d2.charAt(i) == tips.charAt(j)) id2 = j;
        }
        if (id1 > id2)
            return 2;
        else if (id2 > id1)
            return 1;
        else
            continue;
    }
    return 0;
}

public static String strLower(String str, char ziman){
    final StringBuilder mutable = new StringBuilder(str);
    final StringBuilder yedek = new StringBuilder(str.toLowerCase());
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (ziman == '?' && mutable.charAt(i) == 'I')
            mutable.setCharAt(i, 'i');
        else if (ziman == '*' && mutable.charAt(i) == 'I')
            mutable.setCharAt(i, 'ı');
        else mutable.setCharAt(i,yedek.charAt(i));
    }
    return mutable.toString();
}
```

edit:
in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
....
</manifest...>
```

Answer (score 6):

The [Collator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) class should come in-handy here. To quote from the doc,

> The Collator class performs locale-sensitive String comparison. You use this class to build searching and sorting routines for natural language text.

So try something like this:

```
Collator unicodeCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.UNICODE_LOCALE_EXTENSION);
Collections.sort(yourListOfCharacters, unicodeCollator);
```

Note that we are able to call [`java.util.Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) directly as above, because Collator implements the Comparator interface.

If for whatever reasons `Locale.UNICODE_LOCALE_EXTENSION` doesn't work, here's the [full list of supported locales](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html#util-text). And you can create your own locale using the [Locale constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#Locale(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Comment: Collator unicodeCollator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.UNICODE_LOCALE_EXTENSION);

Error:(145, 63) error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to Locale

Comment: @MazlumÖzdoğan You can try with the other supported locales defined in the link I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can build your own comparison so that, no matter what characters you are dealing with, it is going to sort the way you want. As you can see from the following code, I have set the comparison value by counting from `a-z` so that a=0, b=1...etc Then, I used the bubble sort strategy, which is basically switching the smallest elements continuously to the left and shifting others to the right.

```js
public class Sort {

    public static String compare(String compare1, String compare2) {

        for (int i = 0; i < compare1.length(); i++) {
            if (letterValue(compare1, i) < letterValue(compare2, i)) {
                return compare1;
            } else if (letterValue(compare1, i) > letterValue(compare2, i)) {
                return compare2;
            } else if (letterValue(compare1, i) == -1 || letterValue(compare2, i) == -1) {
                System.out.print("Some letters are not within the alphabet!");
            }
        }
        return compare1;
    }

    public static boolean smaller(String compare1, String compare2) {

        if (compare(compare1, compare2).equalsIgnoreCase(compare1)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static int letterValue(String input, int letterPosition) {

        String order = "abcçdeêfghiîjklmnopqrsştûuvwxyz";
        int value = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < order.length(); i++) {
            if (input.toLowerCase().charAt(letterPosition) == order.charAt(i)) {
                value = i;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = {"BARÊZ", "ÇÊneR", "ASTÛ", "badîn", "BADÎN"};
        String swap;
        int i, d;

        for (i = 0; i < (input.length - 1); i++) {
            for (d = 0; d < input.length - i - 1; d++) {
                if (!smaller(input[d], input[d + 1])) {
                    swap = input[d];
                    input[d] = input[d + 1];
                    input[d + 1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sorted list: ");

        for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(input[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output

> Sorted list:
>
> ASTÛ badîn BADÎN BARÊZ ÇÊneR